# x has to be a floating point tensor since it's going to be scaled. Got a <dtype: 'string'> tensor instead

Tags: python, keras, jupyter-notebook, sklearn-pandas

I am getting this error when trying to train the model using sklearn train_split method. I have add some data points in to an array and then have created an array of array. Then that array is converted to a numpy array. Any idea how this error is generated and can be solved?

```
 if start_time < end_time:

         if value[9:] == "A":
             data.append(80)
         else:
             data.append(int(value[9:]))
     else:
         allData.append(data)
         data = []
         if value[9:] == "A":
             data.append(80)
         else:
             data.append(int(value[9:]))
         endTime_obj = endTime_obj + datetime.timedelta(0, 30)
         end_time = endTime_obj.time()
     #         print("else: ", end_time)

     if dataPoints.index(value) == len(dataPoints)-1:
         allData.append(data)
     else:
         pass

 allData = np.array(allData) 

 labels = np.array(labels)

    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    train_data, test_data, train_labels, test_labels = train_test_split(allData, labels, test_size=0.1, random_state=1)
    # Embedding
      max_features = 30000
      maxlen = (1,)
      embedding_size = 128

    # Convolution
      kernel_size = 16
      filters = 128
      pool_size = 4

     LSTM
     lstm_output_size = 30

    # Training
      batch_size = 40
      epochs = 15

    model = Sequential()
    # model.add(Embedding(max_features, embedding_size, input_length=maxlen))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(Conv1D(filters,
                 kernel_size,
                 padding='valid',
                 activation='relu',
                 strides=2))
    model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=pool_size))
    model.add(LSTM(lstm_output_size))
    model.add(Dense(6, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Activation('softmax'))

    model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

    history = model.fit(train_data, train_labels,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=epochs,
          validation_data=(validation_data, validation_labels))
```

----------Error--------------------------

```
ValueError Traceback (most recent call last)
  <ipython-input-15-381a00c7e200> in <module>
      2           batch_size=batch_size,
      3           epochs=epochs,
----> 4           validation_data=(validation_data, validation_labels))

C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
    707         steps=steps_per_epoch,
    708         validation_split=validation_split,
--> 709         shuffle=shuffle)
    710 
    711     # Prepare validation data.

C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in _standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, batch_size, check_steps, steps_name, steps, validation_split, shuffle, extract_tensors_from_dataset)
    2556       else:
    2557         cast_inputs = x_input
 -> 2558       self._set_inputs(cast_inputs)
    2559     else:
    2560       y_input = y

C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in _set_inputs(self, inputs, outputs, training)
    2774       kwargs = {'training': training} if self._expects_training_arg else {}
    2775       try:
 -> 2776         outputs = self(inputs, **kwargs)
    2777       except NotImplementedError:
    2778         # This Model or a submodel is dynamic and hasn't overridden

C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py in __call__(self, inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    632                     outputs = base_layer_utils.mark_as_return(outputs, acd)
    633                 else:
--> 634                   outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    635 
    636             except TypeError as e:

C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\sequential.py in call(self, inputs, training, mask)
    259         kwargs['training'] = training
    260 
--> 261       outputs = layer(inputs, **kwargs)
    262 
    263       # `outputs` will be the inputs to the next layer.

C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py in __call__(self, inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    632                     outputs = base_layer_utils.mark_as_return(outputs, acd)
    633                 else:
--> 634                   outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    635 
    636             except TypeError as e:

C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\layers\core.py in call(self, inputs, training)
    160     output = tf_utils.smart_cond(training,
    161                                  dropped_inputs,
--> 162                                  lambda: array_ops.identity(inputs))
    163     return output
    164 

C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\utils\tf_utils.py in smart_cond(pred, true_fn, false_fn, name)
     56         pred, true_fn=true_fn, false_fn=false_fn, name=name)
     57   return smart_module.smart_cond(
---> 58       pred, true_fn=true_fn, false_fn=false_fn, name=name)
     59 
     60 

C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\smart_cond.py in smart_cond(pred, true_fn, false_fn, name)
     57   else:
     58     return control_flow_ops.cond(pred, true_fn=true_fn, false_fn=false_fn,
---> 59                                  name=name)
     60 
     61 

C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py in new_func(*args, **kwargs)
    505                 'in a future version' if date is None else ('after %s' % date),
    506                 instructions)
--> 507       return func(*args, **kwargs)
    508 
    509     doc = _add_deprecated_arg_notice_to_docstring(

C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py in cond(pred, true_fn, false_fn, strict, name, fn1, fn2)
    1975     try:
    1976       context_t.Enter()
 -> 1977       orig_res_t, res_t = context_t.BuildCondBranch(true_fn)
    1978       if orig_res_t is None:
    1979         raise ValueError("true_fn must have a return value.")

C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py in BuildCondBranch(self, fn)
    1812     """Add the subgraph defined by fn() to the graph."""
    1813     pre_summaries = ops.get_collection(ops.GraphKeys._SUMMARY_COLLECTION)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
 -> 1814     original_result = fn()
    1815     post_summaries = ops.get_collection(ops.GraphKeys._SUMMARY_COLLECTION)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    1816     if len(post_summaries) > len(pre_summaries):

C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\layers\core.py in dropped_inputs()
    156           noise_shape=self._get_noise_shape(inputs),
    157           seed=self.seed,
--> 158           rate=self.rate)
    159 
    160     output = tf_utils.smart_cond(training,

C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py in new_func(*args, **kwargs)
    505                 'in a future version' if date is None else ('after %s' % date),
    506                 instructions)
--> 507       return func(*args, **kwargs)
    508 
    509     doc = _add_deprecated_arg_notice_to_docstring(

C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\nn_ops.py in dropout(x, keep_prob, noise_shape, seed, name, rate)
    4168     raise ValueError("You must provide a rate to dropout.")
    4169 
 -> 4170   return dropout_v2(x, rate, noise_shape=noise_shape, seed=seed, name=name)
    4171 
    4172 

C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\nn_ops.py in dropout_v2(x, rate, noise_shape, seed, name)
    4213     if not x.dtype.is_floating:
    4214       raise ValueError("x has to be a floating point tensor since it's going to"
 -> 4215                        " be scaled. Got a %s tensor instead." % x.dtype)
    4216     if isinstance(rate, numbers.Real):
    4217       if not (rate >= 0 and rate < 1):

ValueError: x has to be a floating point tensor since it's going to be scaled. Got a <dtype: 'string'> tensor instead.
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit hard to say since I can't actually see your data, but you could try:

```
all_data = np.array(all_data)
refined_data = all_data.astype(np.float)
```